# Google Sheets formula to add column to array?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets I have a 2D array, with unpredictable size, returned by a Query:

```
08-02-2020 | Red
10-02-2020 | Brown
12-02-2020 | Green
```

Now I'd like to add a third column containing the constant "Golf" to the array. For instance:

```
08-02-2020 | Red   | Golf
10-02-2020 | Brown | Golf
12-02-2020 | Green | Golf
```

Is there a way to add a column to the initial array? Could not tame this with arrayformula...

current query:

```
=query(transpose(query(transpose(query(transpose(query(A1:11)),"select * where Col1 > 0")),"select * where Col1 <> ''",1)),"select * where Col2 > 0")
```

Comment: what is your query formula?

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: do you have more columns than 77 ?

Comment: No.................................

Comment: interesting, I did something similair many moons ago with a dynamic `Total` row using [this guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-total-row/) I'm curious to see what magic player0 comes up with without appScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:11)), 
 "where Col1 > 0")), 
 "where Col1 <> ''", 1)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "Col"&TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:11)), 
 "where Col1 > 0")), "where Col1 <> ''", 1)), 
 "where Col2 > 0"))))), "'Golf'")&" where Col2 > 0"))
```

Comment: It took me a little to understand the edits.... What can I say? You're  genius! (Sent an email to your address). Many thanks